# MySQL time_zone 'current session' - is it IP or Connection?

Tags: mysql, mydac

I have a project that is, intermittently, changing the time_zone value from a user defined value, to SYSTEM, and I am trying to determine if MySQL considers 'the current session' ([MySQL TimeZone](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html)) the connection, or, the workstation IP that the connection is coming from.

Basically, if it's not per connection, then something else is connecting to MySQL and changing the time_zone value back to SYSTEM, which is then having an impact on my already connected software.

If it is per connection, then I am back to trying to figure out WHERE the time_zone is being reset.

For further info, my project is written in Delphi XE3, using the MyDAC components for DB connections.  When the project loads, I read a connection file and, if there is a time_zone string set, I execute the 'Set Time_zone' query.  The connection stays active through-out the applications run lifetime and is global to the application (i.e. I don't create/connect other connections from this application to the DB).

Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: A session is a connection.

Comment: Does your session go idle for long periods of time? The server may be disconnecting you after a timeout, and the Delphi library may re-connect automatically. Session settings will be lost when that happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A MySQL session corresponds to a connection.

The MySQL server automatically disconnects idle sessions after a timeout, based on the value of the system variable [`wait_timeout`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout), which defaults to 28800 seconds (8 hours). It sounds like Delphi is automatically reconnecting your session, but per-session settings will be lost when this happens.

You should change your application so that it sends the timezone setting if it has been idle for a long period of time. You could also increase the `wait_timeout` (the maximum value is 2147483, 24.85 days).

Comment: Thanks, that's what I figured, just wanted to get it clarified before I went down a rabbit hole of code that had NOTHING to do with my issue - I'll have to add something to the MyDAC component to detect the reconnect and resend the time_zone information